# How to check does string contains start and end - date

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of object that I need to iterate through. I'm trying to check that is contain the following string date : `"7/2/2019 - 7/31/2019"`.

My issue is that my regex is not working :

`const dateType = /(\d{4})([\/-])(\d{1,2})\2(\d{1,2})/;`

I tried to filter trough this array of objects and check with a regex that current `object.name` string contain said string date but as before, my regex is problematic.

```
  const isMatch = this.state.selectedFilters.filter((filter) => 
     dateType.test(filter.name));

      if (isMatch) {
        // ...
      }
```

How to make my regex match this format of dates : `"7/2/2019 - 7/31/2019"`?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/((0?[1-9])|([12][0-9])|(3[01]))\/((\d{4})|(\d{2}))\s*-\s*((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/((0?[1-9])|([12][0-9])|(3[01]))\/((\d{4})|(\d{2}))
```

[Here Is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rHSAUB/1)

Comment: With this format the following will match : 99/99/9999 - 99/99/99

Comment: I am changing it now.

Comment: My pleasure ( ;

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that will work : `^(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)\d{4} - (((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)\d{4}$`

The format is `mm/dd/yyy - mm/dd/yyy`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment library to determine whether this date range is valid or not.

For example:

```
let dateRange = "7/2/2019 - 7/31/2019";
let start = dateRange.split('-')[0];
let end = dateRange.split('-')[1];

moment(start).isValid(); // true
moment(end).isValid(); // true
```

you can combine it with your desired date format like so:

```
moment('17/23/2019').format("M/D/YYYY"); // print invalid date
```